# c++ string casting

Tags: c++, string

I am having problem with string concatination.

```
std::deque<std::string> fileNamesVector;
double * res_array;
string *strarr;

size = fileNamesVector.size();
res_array = new double[size];
strarr = new string [size];
```

I need to append res_array with 4 spaces followed by filenamevector.
How can I do this.

```
strarr[i] = res_array[i] + "     " + fileNamesVector[i];
```

But it gives errors. Saying "exp must have arithmetic or enum type"
Please help.

Comment: `res_array[i]` is a `double` and `"      "` is a `char *`. I'm not sure what should happen if you add a double to a pointer, but I'm sure it's not good.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Cant its a assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, there is no implicit conversion between a double, a `char *` or `std::string`.

`res_array[i] + "   "` is trying to add a double to `char *`, so the compiler tries an implicit conversion, but none exists, so it gives you an error saying that `operator+` needs numerical types.

You will instead need to explicitly convert `res_array[i]` to a string.

```
// File: convert.h
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class BadConversion : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  BadConversion(std::string const& s)
    : std::runtime_error(s)
    { }
};

inline std::string stringify(double x)
{
  std::ostringstream o;
  if (!(o << x))
    throw BadConversion("stringify(double)");
  return o.str();
}
```

[The example above is from The C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/convert-num-to-string.html), even though there are many stackoverflow questions dedicated to this topic, TC++FAQ deserves the real shout out for being OG :)

Or with C++11, use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
strarr[i] = std::to_string(res_array[i]) + "     " + fileNamesVector[i];
```

Comment: You may also want to note that C++11 now has a `std::to_string` that takes a double. Unless you want to do specific formatting, it's much less clunky than having to break out `ostringstream`

Comment: True "  ", is type const char*, , but `fileNamesVector[i]` is `std::string`, as is `strarr[i]` so while the compiler is trying to add a double to char*, it ultimately ends up trying to get to std::string, which also doesn't have an implicit conversion.

Comment: @slavik262 I didn't know that. Cool C++ is getting modern!

Comment: You probably want to make `stringify` a template function (if you don't use `std::to_string`).

Comment: @Alan I am beginner.

how do i use the piece of code you have posted.

Comment: @user1733911 that's okay. We all were beginners at one point :)

Comment: @Alan how do i use it? Do i make a header file convert.h
and then use it as stringify(res_array[i]).

Comment: @user1733911: Yes you could do that, or you could just place the code inside your main.cpp

Comment: @Alan does not work.
i pasted the codes after the beginning of main
and it points error near curly bracket asking for ;
inline std::string stringify(double x) {

Comment: @user1733911 That is because unless you use a forward declaration, the code must be placed above where it is used. Read up on [function prototypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) and [forward declarations](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on C++11 yet, you should cast your `double` to a `std::string` using `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
...
strarr[i] = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(res_array[i]) + "     " + fileNamesVector[i];
```

http://www.boost.org/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

On a side note, I would very strongly recommend against using raw pointers for memory management. If you want a variable-sized array `std::vector` should be your first choice, not `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Does boost come standard with any compilers pre C++11?

Comment: Hi i tried this but error says cant open source file boost/lexical_cast.hpp

Comment: As far as I know, Boost does not come with any compilers. However, it is in practice part of almost any serious C++ development effort. You'll need to download it and set it up. The process for how you do that is beyond the scope of this question, as it depends on compiler and operating system. http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.52.0/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use raw arrays and arrays of raw pointers when e.g. `std::vector` will do.

It's there in the standard library for a reason.

Namely, to make your life a lot easier. :-)

```
#include <assert.h>     // assert
#include <iostream>     // wcout, endl
#include <queue>        // std::dequeue
#include <stddef.h>     // ptrdiff_t
#include <string>       // std::string, std::to_string
#include <utility>      // std::begin, std::end
#include <vector>       // std::vector
using namespace std;

typedef ptrdiff_t       Size;
typedef Size            Index;

template< class Type >
Size size( Type const& c ) { return end( c ) - begin( c ); }

string spaces( Size const n ) { return string( n, ' ' ); }

wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, string const& s )
{
    return (stream << s.c_str());
}

#ifdef __GNUC__
// Possibly add a workaround implementation of std::to_string
#endif

int main()
{
    deque<string>   file_names_vector;
    vector<double>  res_arr;

    file_names_vector.push_back( "blah.foo" );
    res_arr.push_back( 3.14 );

    assert( file_names_vector.size() == res_arr.size() );
    Size const size = file_names_vector.size();
    vector<string>  str_arr;

    for( Index i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        str_arr.push_back( to_string( res_arr[i] ) + spaces( 5 ) + file_names_vector[i] );
    }

    for( auto const& s : str_arr )
    {
        wcout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cheers-and-hth-Alf Thanks but I am beginner(sorry) and I dont know how to use this piece of code.